# How to efficiently extract all slices of given length using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to extract all slices of length 4 along 0th axis of a 2-dim tensor. So far I can do it mixing pure Python with tensorflow.

```
r = test.shape[0] # test should be a tensor
n = 4
a_list = list(range(r))
the_list = np.array([a_list[slice(i, i+n)] for i in range(r - n+1)])
test_stacked = tf.stack(tf.gather(test, the_list))
```

What would be an efficient way of doing that without using pure Python? Note that the "test" array is actually supposed to be a tensor, thus its shape isn't known before I execute the first part of the graph.

A full vanilla example:

```
array = np.array([[0, 1],[1, 2],[2, 3],[3, 4],[4, 5],[5, 6]])
array.shape # (6,2)

r = array.shape[0]
n = 4
a_list = list(range(r))
the_list = np.array([a_list[slice(i, i+n)] for i in range(r - n+1)])

result = array[the_list] # all possible slices of length 4 of the array along 0th axis
result.shape # (3, 4, 2)
```

result:

```
[[[0 1]
  [1 2]
  [2 3]
  [3 4]]

 [[1 2]
  [2 3]
  [3 4]
  [4 5]]

 [[2 3]
  [3 4]
  [4 5]
  [5 6]]]
```

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes! Edited the question to include an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try the more general `tf.extract_image_patches`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[0, 1],[1, 2],[2, 3],[3, 4],[4, 5],[5, 6]])
# tf.extract_image_patches requires a [batch, in_rows, in_cols, depth] tensor
a = a[None, :, :, None]
b = tf.extract_image_patches(a,
  ksizes=[1, 4, 2, 1],
  strides=[1, 1, 1, 1],
  rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
  padding='VALID')
b = tf.reshape(tf.squeeze(b), [-1, 4, 2])

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(b.eval())
```

Comment: Works really great. Seems a bit strange though that this use case would only be accommodated by an image-specific function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [gather_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) is what you are looking for.

```
# a is a tensor of size (6, 2)

def get_indices(l, d):
    return [[[j] for j in range(i, i + d)] for i in range(l - d + 1)]

b = tf.gather_nd(a, get_indices(6, 4))
# b is a tensor of shape (3, 4, 2)
```

Comment: Is the function get_indices going to be a part of the computational graph somehow? For example if the first argument (length of the first dimension) is going to have to be computed in the graph before the gather_nd is called?

Comment: I guess yes, but you can get it from say the `feed_dict` if you pass the 1st dimension size thru it. The indices will be generated for different sizes and it's likely not going to be slowing the computation down. And tf methods are used to construct the computation graph so you don't have to worry about forward and backward propagation since tensorflow takes care everything.

Comment: I can't feed it through the feed_dict because I don't know it before the batch is created (the size of the dimension depends on what is the longest sequence in the batch). Sorry that I wasn't clear enough to specify that in the question.

Comment: In this case you can ask another question/edit this question detailing the situation you encountered. more information will always help.